# Out of Phase Path Difference?

Tags: waves, interference

I know that if two sources are out of phase by $a$, both with wavelength $b$, $(a\cdot b)/2\pi$ must be added to the path difference when calculating interference. Why is this? And what is the intuition behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Superposition in this context is the adding together of two sinusoidal variations of the same frequency and speed.
It is convenient to talk about path lengths in terms of wavelengths and also compare path differences in terms of wavelengths.
A wavelength is the minimum distance between two particles which are moving synchronously.
Noting that $\sin (\theta)=\sin (\theta+2\pi)$ another way of describing a wavelength is to say that it is the distance between two particles which differ in phase by $2\pi$ radians.
So a phase difference of $4\pi = 2 \times 2\pi$ is equivalent to a path difference of 2 wavelengths.

In your example a path difference of $b$ (one wavelength) is equivalent to a phase difference of $2\pi$.

So by using simple ratios a path difference of $a$ is equivalent to a phase difference of $a \times \dfrac{2\pi}{b}$.

Answer (score 2):

The path difference needs to be augmented by the wavelength offset of the phase difference so that one can calculate the actual superposition of the two waves.  It's a mathematical calculation, not an intuition.

Consider two sources of frequency $f$, with an initial phase difference of $\alpha$ radians:
$$S_1=A\sin(2\pi f t + \alpha)$$
$$S_2=A\sin(2\pi f t )$$
As the waves travel from the sources to a common point in space, the wave displacement, $y_n$, of each wave at a common point in space will be:
$$y_1=A\sin(2\pi f t -\dfrac{2\pi}{\lambda}x_1 + \alpha)$$
$$y_2=A\sin(2\pi f t -\dfrac{2\pi}{\lambda}x_2 )$$

where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the distances from each source to the common point, respectively.

In order for constructive interference to occur, the difference in the arguments of these sine functions must be a multiple of $2\pi$:

$$2\pi f t -\dfrac{2\pi}{\lambda}x_1 + \alpha-(2\pi f t -\dfrac{2\pi}{\lambda}x_2 )=2\pi n$$

$$\dfrac{2\pi}{\lambda}(x_2-x_1)+\alpha=2\pi n$$

$$(x_2-x_1)+\dfrac{\alpha\lambda}{2\pi}=n.$$

$n$ can be any integer. In the case of your question, let $n=0$.

For destructive interference one would have an sine argument different of $(2n\pm 1)\pi$.